# Real use(problem) of Encrypting Environment Files with Laravel

Tags: laravel, encryption, environment-variables

I was reading this article [Encrypting Environment Files](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#encrypting-environment-files) to encrypt and decrypt the `.env` content.

as per the documentation, after running `php artisan env:encrypt` command, it generates a new `.env.encrypted` file, and also the output of the command is returning a Key.

To decrypt the content, the command is looking for `LARAVEL_ENV_ENCRYPTION_KEY` which always changes as soon as I encrypt the content. So I don't understand the best use of this feature.

**Real Use case.**

- Let's suppose, I have added a new variable in the `.env` file and encrypted the file.
  Now I shared this file with other team members, now I have to share the key as well to decrypt it.
- after decrypting, another team member adds a new variable and he has to follow the same routine. encrypt, and share the key.
- for decryption, you have to remove the `.env` file, and obviously `LARAVEL_ENV_ENCRYPTION_KEY` will never be found(or which might be changed because of the latest encryption), so you have to pass the `--key` option while decrypting the content.

Answer (score 0):

> *'To decrypt the content, the command is looking for `LARAVEL_ENV_ENCRYPTION_KEY` which always changes as soon as I encrypt
> the content. So I don't understand the best use of this feature.'*

You can always provide your own encryption key while decrypting using:

`php artisan env:decrypt --force --key=3UVsEgGVK36XN82KKeyLFMhvosbZN1aF`

In addition, you can encrypt by provide the ***same*** encryption key using:

`php artisan env:encrypt --force --key=3UVsEgGVK36XN82KKeyLFMhvosbZN1aF`

---

The team members don't need to share a new encryption key every time they add a new environment variable to the `.env` file since they will always be using the **same** key to encrypt the edited `.env` file before adding/committing the regenerated `.env.encrypted` file to source control.

Comment: but I don't want to pass the key all the time(while encryption or decryption). according to the current use case, I am not able to run `php artisan env:decrypt` command

Comment: @SachinKumar What do you mean by *'I am not able to run `php artisan env:decrypt` command'*? Don't the team members, you inclusive, have access to the terminal to run commands on their local computers?

Comment: when I run this command `php artisan env:decrypt` it is asking me to remove the old `.env` file, I removed and now it is saying `key is missing`

Comment: I want to run the commands without the key flag. is this possible or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: *In order to overwrite an existing environment file, you may provide the `--force` option to the `env:decrypt` command:*  `php artisan env:decrypt --force --key=3UVsEgGVK36XN82KKeyLFMhvosbZN1aF`

Comment: @SachinKumar If you don't want to provide the encryption key in the *decryption command*, then what's the point/purpose of sharing the key with other team members?

Comment: but that would be endless. because every time my team member adds a new key in the `.env` file, they have to re-share the key with all team members.

Comment: I really don't understand the use of the `LARAVEL_ENV_ENCRYPTION_KEY` env variable. If I added this variable in `.env` then I can encrypt the `.env` but can't decrypt because for this I have to remove the `.env` file then what is the use of the `LARAVEL_ENV_ENCRYPTION_KEY` variable?

Comment: @SachinKumar They **don't** have to set the `LARAVEL_ENV_ENCRYPTION_KEY` environment variable since it will be **ignored** either way when an encryption key is **explicitly** provided when running any of the `php artisan env:...` commands with the `--key=...` option.